# csv to xml and lambda expressions

Tags: c#, xml, csv, lambda

I have the following piece of code to convert a csv to an XML.

```
var xml = new XElement("root",
        lines.Where((line, index) => index > 0).Select(line => new XElement("TEST",
        line.Split(',').Select((column, index) => new XElement(headers[index], column)))))
```

I do get the big picture here. As in I get what each line does but I do not understand why some part like (line, index) is used. does this mean that when the index>0 then it sets the line to be that respective value?

I'd appreciate if someone can break this down for me. would be great if the lambda expressions are not used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it *really* helps if you indent more clearly:

```
var xml = new XElement("root",
    lines.Where((line, index) => index > 0) // Skips first line
         .Select(line => new XElement("TEST",
             line.Split(',')
                 .Select((column, index) => new XElement(headers[index], column)))))
```

In Visual Studio I would probably use more horizontal space, putting the `line.Split` on the same line as `new XElement("TEST")`.

Now, any `Where` or `Select` call taking a lambda such as `(value, index)` received two pieces of information per item:

- The value itself
- The index within the sequence

So `.Where((line, index) => index > 0` just means "ignore the first line". It would be more clearly written as `.Skip(1)`.

Next, `.Select((column, index) => new XElement(headers[index], column))` takes each column, and creates an element with the corresponding header as the element name, and `column` as the value. Personally, I'd write this using `Zip`, leaving:

```
var xml = new XElement("root",
    lines.Skip(1)
         .Select(line => new XElement("TEST",
             line.Split(',')
                 .Zip(headers, (value, header) => new XElement(header, value)))))
```

Comment: If I have one column in a column header named "DATA=NITSService", it throws an error saying: 
system.xml.xmlexception the '=' character hexadecimal value 0x3a cannot be included in a name.

how do I get rid of this?

Comment: I actually removed the = sign from the string. but please do let me know if you know another way to do this.

Comment: @user2697903: Well no, that's just invalid XML... you simply can't have an XML element or attribute name including `=`.

Comment: how would the code looks like if Lines was an arrayList ?

Comment: @user2697903: Why would you have an `ArrayList`? You could use `Cast`, but really it's been 10 years since it's been a good idea to use non-generic collections...